# Add a web.config key for always redirect when get an unhandled exceptions

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications, web-config

I once saw that was possible to do something like adding a key in the web.config file to redirect to a default error page everytime a unhandled exception is found.

Is it possible? how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a [CustomErrors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hfz6fc(VS.71).aspx) section to your web.config.

```
<customErrors defaultRedirect="ErrorPage.aspx" mode="RemoteOnly" />
```

Comment: Note the remoteonly will behave such that if you access the site from the local lan/intranet then it will not perform the redirect.  The reason for this is so local developers and see the actual exception occuring while those accessing it from the public will see the ErrorPage.aspx

Answer (score 6):

Yes the `customErrors` section of the web.config.

```
<customErrors defaultRedirect="~/GenericError.aspx" mode="On" />
```

This will redirect your users to what `defaultRedirect` (URL) when they encounter an error.

You can also specify where they go based on the HTTP response code

```
<customErrors defaultRedirect="~/GenericError.aspx" mode="On">
    <error statusCode="500" redirect="~/Error.aspx"/>
    <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/NotFound.aspx"/>
</customErrors>
```

Here is the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hfz6fc.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

```
<customErrors defaultRedirect="~/serverErrorPage.aspx" mode="On" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite"/>
```

It's not suitable for real use prior to .NET3.5 service pack 1, as until then the redirectMode attribute wasn't there and it would always act with the default value `"ResponseRedirect"` which would redirect to the error page instead of showing it directly; so instead of giving an error response it would "successfully" redirect to another page, and then *that* would return the error!